# Grid system layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning nuts and bolts of the grid system and even though
I followed examples and templates from other developers I can't get
my test project appear in two columns. It keeps showing stacked.

Here's the bit of code I'm learning on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .col-md-8 {
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    body {
        background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
             <p>Just some random text. First column.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <p>Another random text. Second column.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>



  </body>
  </html>
```

Like I said this bit of code worked for others for some reason. They just added more columns like it was a game. I can't even get 2 columns.

Comment: What seemed odd to me was they didn't need to play with "row" displaying at all.

Comment: This has two columns: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYNVWr Maybe your path to the css is incorrect? What do you see when you open the dev tools?

Comment: If you are learning and Bootstrap is not a requirement for you project I may suggest to have a read at this article https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

There are so many ways to do CSS grids, not just row-based ones. Also Bootstrap 4 is moving to flexbox which is a very different model than floats.

But then again, try to code it up from scratch yourself and you will realise it's not so hard.

Comment: Yes "sufmuggle". I just had a look in developer's tools and console says the css link failed to load. Gotta use different one.

Comment: Odd ... I tried to use the latest css link from Bootstrap still getting failed to load. Strange. I tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: "tmslnz" thanks for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the following:

- you would like two columns so that `div.col-md-8` and `div.col-md-4` are next to each other
- currently the two divs are stacked (sitting on top of each other)

This [codepen is your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYNVWr) with a reference to [bootstrap-min](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) (3.3.7). And it seems to work as you expect. Below you have to click on `full page` to see the desired layout; inline it seems to interfere with the style of this page.

1. Maybe your path to the css is incorrect?
2. What do you see when you open the [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)?

Does this solve your problem?

#### Code example

```css
body { background-color: grey; }
div { color: white; text-align: center;}
.col-md-8 { background-color: red; }
.col-md-4 { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>Just some random text. First column.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Another random text. Second column.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```